# gcc segmentation fault due to a pointer variable that changed itself

Tags: c, gcc

Let's consider follwing code.

**message_word.h**

```
struct array_int64{
        int size;
        long* value;
};
struct array_int64* array_int64_create(int size);
int array_int64_get(void* value, const struct array_int64* array, int index);
int array_int64_set(struct array_int64* array, long value, int index);
void array_int64_free(struct array_int64* array);
struct hello_message{
        struct array_int64* test;
};
struct hello_message* hello_message_create();
void hello_message_free(struct hello_message* msg);
```

**message_word.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "word_message.h"

struct array_int64* array_int64_create(int size){
        struct array_int64* new_array = (struct array_int64*)malloc(sizeof(struct array_int64));
        new_array->size = size;
        new_array->value = (long*)malloc(sizeof(long) * (new_array->size));
        return new_array;
}
int array_int64_get(void* value, const struct array_int64* array, int index){
        long* vvalue = (long*)value;
        if(index >= array->size)
                return -1;
        *vvalue = (array->value)[index];
        return 0;
}
int array_int64_set(struct array_int64* array, long value, int index){
        if(index >= array->size)
                return -1;
        array->value[index] = value;
        return 0;
}
void array_int64_free(struct array_int64* array){
        if(array != NULL && array->value != NULL)
                free(array->value);
        if(array != NULL)
                free(array);
}
struct hello_message* hello_message_create(){
        struct hello_message* new_msg = (struct hello_message*)malloc(sizeof(struct hello_message));
        new_msg->test = array_int64_create(5);
        return new_msg;
}
void hello_message_free(struct hello_message* msg){
        if(msg == NULL) return;
        array_int64_free(msg->test);
        free(msg);
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "word_message.h"
#include <stdio.h>

//struct hello_message* msg = NULL;

int main(void)
{
        struct hello_message* msg = hello_message_create();
        //msg = hello_message_create();
        array_int64_set(msg->test, 10, 0);
        int number;
        array_int64_get(&number, msg->test, 0);
        printf("value is: %d\n", number);
        array_int64_get(&number, msg->test, 0);
        printf("value is: %d\n", number);
        hello_message_free(msg);
        return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run this code with gcc-9.3.0 or gcc-7.5.0 on Ubuntu **the msg reference address changes itself when array_int64_get** is executed. However, if you make msg a global variable like in the comment, it does not change.When I compile and run this code on Ubuntu 18, gcc-7.5.0 on a Raspberry Pi (ARM), everything works fine. It also works fine on windows. So is this a bug in gcc?

**This is the result of running on ubuntu18(x86)+gcc-9.3.0**
[running on ubuntu18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0Usi.png)

**This is the result of running it on a Raspberry Pi**
[run on raspberry pi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOS2c.png)

Comment: You are taking the address of an `int` and casting it to `long*`. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: `int number; array_int64_get(&number, msg->test, 0);` is incorrect. If you're going to treat `number` as a `long` inside the function it should also be one outside the function.  You might consider using `int64_t` instead. Your code may work in Windows because `int` and `long` are the same size and neither is 64 bit.

Comment: As an aside, why would you want set to take a long, but then have the get use a void*, rather than a long*?  It would reduce the likelyhood of this type of error.

Comment: Sorry, I thought this problem would occur in either C or C++ so I labeled it C++, but of course this is a piece of C code

Comment: @RetiredNinja thank you for your answer sincerely.I think this is the root cause.

Comment: [Images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should not be used for textual data, such as output and error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int array_int64_get(void* value, const struct array_int64* array, int index){
        long* vvalue = (long*)value;
        ...
 }

 int main() {
        int number;
        array_int64_get(&number, msg->test, 0);
 }
```

You are passing an `int` with a pointer and then reading it as `long`. That's invalid. If you want it `long`, be it `long`.

Use `long`s everywhere, and if your functions wants a `long` make it take a `long`.

```
int array_int64_get(long *vvalue, const struct array_int64* array, int index){
    ...
}

 int main() {
        int number;
        array_int64_get(&number, ...); // compiler warning!
        long correctnumber;
        array_int64_get(&correctnumber, ...); // all fine!
 }
```

Conceptually, your code is odd. `long` *is not* 64-bit long, it's **at least** 32-bits long. It can have 32-bits, 64-bits, 1000-bits. For 64-bit, use `uint64_t` or `int64_t` from `#include <stdint.h>`. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer .

`free(NULL)` is totally fine - no need to check for it.

[Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)